# responsive HTML form with labels

Tags: html, css

I am using this css code:

```
form > div {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
form > div > div {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
form > div > label {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
form > div > div {
  width: 75%;
  float: right;
}
form > div > label {
    font-size: 90%;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=url],
input[type=tel],
input[type=password],
textarea {
    width: 60%;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=email],
input[type=url],
input[type=tel],
input[type=password],
textarea,
select {
    height:35px;
    padding:5px;
    color:#F36F25;
    font-size:16px;
    border: 1px solid #F36F25;
}

input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=email]:focus,
input[type=url]:focus,
input[type=password]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: #F36F25;
  font-weight:bold;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  form > div {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0; 
  }
  form > div > label {
      width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
  form > div > div {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  input[type=text],
  input[type=email],
  input[type=url],
  input[type=password],
  textarea,
  select {
    width: 100%; 
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  form > div > label {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

to create a responsive HTML Form using labels, its working okay but im not sure how to make the labels and form elements inline horizontally, the form elements seem to be displaying lower than the labels

http://jsfiddle.net/17h5da97/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css to the following:

```
form > div > label {
    width: 24%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

form > div > div {
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17h5da97/6/)

Comment: thank you - works great. i have updated it here - http://jsfiddle.net/17h5da97/8/ - how can i make the labels display in the middle vertically ?

Comment: Aren't they in the middle in the updated example? http://jsfiddle.net/17h5da97/6/

Comment: yes - i added a height into form > div > label which caused the issue. thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `padding` on the label element:

```
form > div > label {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    /* padding-right: 10px; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made the labels float left with your css - you also need to make the form inputs float left to get them displaying side-by-side. To do this, add the following CSS rule:

```
form > div > select{
 float: left;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

You could place them inside the div:

```
<div>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <select name="title">
        <option value="Mr" <?php if($contact["title"] == 'Mr') { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Mr</option>
        <option value="Mrs" <?php if($contact["title"] == 'Mrs') { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Mrs</option>
        <option value="Miss" <?php if($contact["title"] == 'Miss') { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Miss</option>
        <option value="Ms" <?php if($contact["title"] == 'Ms') { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Ms</option>
    </select>
<div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/17h5da97/1/

Or you remove float right:

```
form > div > div {
   margin: 0 0 0 0;
   width: 75%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/17h5da97/4/

Or you remove the padding of the label:

```
form > div > label {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/17h5da97/5/

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have padding on the label:

```
form > div > label {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px; // <--- padding
}
```

as the label and the input div's have percentages adding up to 100%, this will disrupt the width and make the div drop down.

try taking width inpercentages from the other two areas and adding this to the padding for a percentage padding like:

```
form > div > label {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
```

with the width of the input div as 70%.

like so: http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/17h5da97/7/

Answer (score 0):

In the label section

```
/*float: left; */

margin: 0 auto;
```